# How can I set up Cygwin to automatically update and download without the GUI?

Tags: cygwin

How can I set up Cygwin to automatically update itself?

How can I get Cygwin to download a package without having to go via the GUI thing?

Comment: Cygwin runs on Windows; this probably belongs on [SU](http://superuser.com/)

Comment: Urgh. Cygwin is a version of Unix.

Comment: I know a good number of people that would cry hearing "Cygwin is a version of Unix", but I guess we'll go with it

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Cygwin : Unix :: Peaches : Trombone (that was on my GRE ;)

Given how [dramatic Cygwin changes](http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/ov-new1.7.html) can be, I'd be really wary of having it done without my explicit consent. If you are daring, you could [invoke cron](http://www.devdaily.com/blog/post/linux-unix/get-crontab-started-running-when-using-cygwin) to run whatever update script you might choose.

If you were looking for the ill-documented `setup.exe --quiet-mode` for unattended operation, there it is.

Answer (score 7):

### Automating Cygwin Installation

Source: [This Wiki Page](http://cygwin.wikia.com/wiki/FAQ#2.2._What_about_an_automated_Cygwin_installation.3F)

> The Cygwin Setup program is designed to be interactive, but there are
>   a few different ways to automate it. If you are deploying to multiple
>   systems, the best way is to run through a full installation once,
>   saving the entire downloaded package tree. Then, on target systems,
>   run setup.exe as a "Local Install" pointed at your downloaded package
>   tree. You could do this non-interactively with the command line
>   options `setup.exe -q -L -l x:\cygwin-local\`, where your downloaded
>   package tree is in `x:\cygwin-local\` (see the next FAQ for an
>   explanation of those options.)
>
> For other options, search the mailing lists with terms such as [cygwin
>   automated setup](http://www.google.com/search?q=cygwin+automated+setup) or [automated cygwin install](http://www.google.com/search?q=automated+cygwin+install).

I have found some of the key places where this is discussed:

1. [Cygwin Mailing List: Clone cygwin-setup settings from one PC to another](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2005-06/msg00806.html)
2. [Cygwin Mail Archive: question on backup](http://www.mail-archive.com/cygwin@cygwin.com/msg118822.html)
3. [Cygwin Mailing List: Automated cygwin install](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2011-09/msg00097.html)
4. [Cygwin Mailing List: Possible to copy whole cygwin folder to different machine?](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2003-10/msg00945.html)
5. [helix' blog: Install cygwin-packages from the cmdline](http://www.he1ix.org/tag/cygwin/)

You may want to look into using `cygcheck` as well.

Also:  I have not tested this myself, but there is now a project called `apt-cyg` which looks like it works in a similar way to debian's apt-get.  Here is the [project page](http://code.google.com/p/apt-cyg/)

### Copy Cygwin Packages to a New System

Here is an easy way I've found to duplicate an installation to multiple systems with updated packages upon install time:

```
#Save some copies of the /etc/setup/installed.db file
cp /etc/setup/installed.db ~/installed.db.bak
cp /etc/setup/installed.db ~/installed.db
#Create a sed script to zero version numbers
cat > ~/zero-version-nums.sed<<-'EOM'
s/-[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9a-zA-Z]\+-[0-9]\+\.tar/-0.0.0.0-0.tar/ 
s/-[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+-[0-9]\.[0-9a-zA-Z]\+\.tar/-0.0-0.0.tar/ 
s/-[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9a-zA-Z]\+-[0-9]\+\.tar/-0.0.0-0.tar/ 
s/-[0-9]\+\.[_+0-9a-zA-Z]\+-[0-9]\+\.tar/-0.0-0.tar/ 
s/-[0-9a-zA-Z]\+-[0-9]\+\.tar/-0-0.tar/ 
s/-[0-9]\+\.tar/-0.tar/ 
EOM
# Change all version numbers to 0 (run sed script)
sed -i -f ~/zero-version-nums.sed ~/installed.db
```

Now simply copy this file to the new machine in `C:\cygwin\etc\setup\installed.db`, and run the Setup.exe installer.  The packages listed should be automatically selected for update.  It may be possible to automate this process using the tips I mentioned above, and [here](http://www.he1ix.org/tag/cygwin/).

Sources:

1. [Cygwin Mailing List](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2005-06/msg00806.html)
2. [Code snippet on Snipplr: Sed script](http://snipplr.com/view/20488/)
3. [Blog Post: Install cygwin-packages from the cmdline](http://www.he1ix.org/tag/cygwin/)
4. [Cygwin Mail Archive: question on backup](http://www.mail-archive.com/cygwin@cygwin.com/msg118822.html)

Answer (score 3):

[Here's an answer](https://superuser.com/a/624731/13743) from superuser about doing an unattended update:

```
cd C:\cygwin
wget -N http://cygwin.com/setup.exe
setup.exe --no-desktop --no-shortcuts --no-startmenu --quiet-mode
```

> You should reboot after the upgrade is completed to prevent cygwin
>   apps from misbehaving due to upgraded cygwin1.dll
>
> `--no-desktop` Disable creation of desktop shortcut
>
> `--no-shortcuts` Disable creation of desktop and start menu
>
> `--no-startmenu` Disable creation of start menu shortcut
>
> `--quiet-mode` Unattended setup mode